# Not able to create thread after reaching count 32751

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, centos7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *my_thread(void *ddd)
{
    printf("Thread created\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    int ret = 0, counter = 0;
    pthread_t et;
    while(1)
    {
        ret = pthread_create(&et, NULL, my_thread, (void *)&counter);
        if(ret)
        {
            printf("Ret = %d, errr = %d, couter = %d\n", ret, errno, counter);
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my C code. checked `ulimit -s` it gives `8192`.I am not using pthred_join because i want to process my data parallel and any how thread will be exited after finishing its job.
output of the program after creating 32750 thred is

```
Thread created 32750
Thread created 32751
Ret = 11, errr = 12, couter = 32751
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [pthread_create man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> A thread may either be joinable or detached.
> ...
>
> Only when a terminated joinable thread has been joined are the last of its
> resources released back to the system.
> ...
>
> When a detached thread terminates, its resources are automatically released
> back to the system:
> ....
>
> By default, a new thread is created in a joinable state, unless attr was set
> to create the thread in a detached state (using thread_attr_setdetachstate(3)).

This means that for any thread you create but do not join, some resources are still kept after it terminates.
After a certain number of threads you will run out of resources.

To avoid this, cou can call `pthread_detach` after creating the thread or use `pthread_attr_setdetachstate` Before you create it.